# Get users by term id

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

In user profiles, I have added a term reference field. In my module, I want to get users that have a term id. Is there a function like `taxonomy_select_nodes` but for users to select users having a taxonomy term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't, but since users are entities, and taxonomy term references are fields, you can use an [`EntityFieldQuery`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) to get this data. You could even wrap it in a function to make your life very easy:

```
function taxonomy_select_users($term_id) {
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery;
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'user')
    ->fieldCondition('field_taxonomy_term_field', 'tid', $term_id);

  $results = $query->execute();

  if (isset($results['user'])) {
    return user_load_multiple(array_keys($results['user']));    
  }

  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: That's the answer.